# xslt include/import path

Tags: php, xslt

I use XSLT as template engine in my PHP framework. Some XSLT files are in different folders,so if I want to include/import xslt template not from main directory I have to type a lot:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">   
    <xsl:import href="dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/layout.xsl"/> 

    <xsl:template name="content">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>action.xsl</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                test
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there any easy way to reduce this `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/layout.xsl` ? `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/` are static (never changes).

Separate template with all includes does not fit, because each template requires different files, and after some time it is difficult to understand what's included and where.

I thought perhaps ​​it is possible to do something with `xml:base` `<xsl:import href="layout.xsl" xml:base="dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/" />`, but do not know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:import href="layout.xsl" xml:base="dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/" />
```

is possible in XSLT 2.0 but not in 1.0.

Did you try it in XSLT 2.0 (e.g. in Saxon), and if so, what was the result?

You cannot put import statements into templates; each import statement must be at the top level below the stylesheet element.

Comment: I'm using PHP `XSLTProcessor` for converting my xslt templates (as I know PHP supports only XSLT 1.0), but `xml:base` works fine for me. Problem is that I have to specify `xml:base` all the time. Maybe it is possible to set `xml:base` just in one place?

Comment: @Tomas, when you say "all the time", do you mean in every import statement? If so, you can put xml:base on the `xsl:stylesheet` element, and all descendants will inherit it. (P.S. I didn't know XSLT 1.0 processors could handle xml:base, but maybe it's an allowed extension. Or maybe PHP's processor is just non-conformant in this regard.)

Answer (score 1):

[XSLT 1.0]

You can't use for example `xsl:import` like this:

```
 <xsl:import href="$mypath"/>
```

because `href`evaluates always to a string. AVT is not allowed either.

---

One possible solution is to **define a specific stylesheet in the target folder** which provides all required imports (and in this stylesheet you will need simple relative paths). In this way the main xsl will need to import only that single specific stylesheet.

For instance, `transformA.xsl` will import `ir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/transformA_imports.xsl` which will import all required files such as `layout.xsl`